# What does String Formatter in java means for $%2$.2f

Tags: java, android

What does **%2$.2F** return when we use in **String.Format** 
eg

```
String.format(Number %1$s amount of $%2$.2f failed, 1245, 1548.3587);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$%2$.2f
```

In this expression, the first `$` is just a literal dollar symbol.

The `%2$` indicates a variable to insert into the string, which will be taken from the second additional argument (after the format string).

The `.2f` means this argument should be formatted as a `float` (the `f` part) and with a precision of 2 digits after `.`